# How to find references on table.insert() method?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a strange issue. I am trying to "Find references" on the insert method of the InventTransferTable table. However, the result set is all insert calls on Common which is essentially all of the uses of insert() in the codebase. A useless result set. Is there a way for me to find only the insert calls for InventTransferTable table specifically? I have done full builds and cross reference builds. I have tried right-clicking the code .insert() and right clicking the AOT node of the method and "Find reference". Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue since platform update 26. Microsoft mentioned in a discussion in the Yammer group of the Insider program that it would be fixed in platform update 29 ([link](https://www.yammer.com/dynamicsaxfeedbackprograms/threads/219669413814272) for those with access). I can confirm that on a development vm based on the VHD with platform update 29 and updated to platform update 30, only four references are shown for the `insert` method of table `InventTransferTable`.

In case you don't have a quick way to access a system with platform update 29 or newer, they are:

> /Classes/InventTransferTableEventHandler/Methods/postInsertHandlerBR -
>   (29, 56) /Classes/ReqTransPoMarkFirm/Methods/createInventTransferTable
>   - (987, 29) /Classes/RetailRTSTransferOrder/Methods/createTransferOrderHeader -
>   (305, 33)
>   /Classes/RetailTransferOrderHandler/Methods/createTransferTable - (94,
>   29)

Comment: I appreciate you pasting the AppSuite model references. Unfortunately, I'm working in a highly custom installation (12 ISV solutions, 250+ customizations). I need it to work across the custom codebase.